# include() fails when running from terminal but not from the web

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that includes another file in an adjacent directory.

Example code:

```
include("../lib/file.php");
```

The code works fine when you access the page running it from a browser but fails (on the mentioned include() line) if I run it from a terminal or cron.

I get a warning that says "No such file or directory in /path/to/file.php" and as a result the class I try to call from that file doesn't exist, which leads to a fatal error.

What would cause this to work from a browser but fail from terminal.

Comment: I guess the path is relative to the php.exe directory when you execute the code from the terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always always always use absolute paths with include:

```
 include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../lib/file.php");
```

Comment: Learn something (the hard way) every day.  Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Always use absolute paths.

As a second thought, running php from terminal will execute php as cli, so the php.ini used is different (usually, `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` instead of `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` if your web service use apache's mod_php or `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` if it runs php as cgi/fastcgi mode) so the configuration may be different (include paths, in your case may matter).